# List to IHierarchicalEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have a list of this object:

```
class Tree
{
    int id
    int value1
    int value2
    int value3
    int parentId
}
```

How can i "cast" this list into an IHierarchicalEnumerable?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a collection like `public class Trees : List<Tree>, IHierarchicalEnumerable
        {
            public IHierarchyData GetHierarchyData(object enumeratedItem)
            {
                return enumeratedItem as IHierarchyData;
            }
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast it if it doesn't implement `IHierarchicalEnumerable` interface. You need to implement the methods of that interface.

```
class Tree: IHierarchicalEnumerable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IHierarchyData GetHierarchyData(object enumeratedItem)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```